# How do i move an image from left to right and right to left in javascript for infinite time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to make a game of pacman using HTML CSS and Javascript. I need to move the ghosts throughout the game. This is the function im using to conrol the movement of the ghost but this function gets called once and then the ghost stops, how can i run it for infinite amount of time ?

```
function moveEnemy() {
        var e1 = document.getElementById("e1");
                if(parseInt(e1.style.left)>10 && parseInt(e1.style.left)<1000)
                    e1.style.left = parseInt(e1.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
                else if(parseInt(e1.style.left)<10 && parseInt(e1.style.top)<500)
                    e1.style.top = parseInt(e1.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
                else if(parseInt(e1.style.left)<10 && parseInt(e1.style.top)>500)
                    e1.style.top = parseInt(e1.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
                else if(parseInt(e1.style.left)>1000 && parseInt(e1.style.top)>500)
                    e1.style.left = parseInt(e1.style.left) - 5 + 'px';

    }
```

I cannot do this using jQuery so a solution using pure JS would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why do you need to create something that's already been created? https://github.com/daleharvey/pacman

Comment: I'd use `requestAnimationFrame`, especially for loops with a short duration. Intervals are a thing of the past for something like this and should really be a fallback at most.

Comment: @vol7ron this is an assignment for my web engineering course :)

Comment: gotcha.  educational is a valid reason

Comment: thanks @Shikkediel , ill look into it aswell :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `setInterval`

```
setInterval(moveEnemy, 1000);
```

This will call the function once every 1 second, if you want another interval, change the `1000` to any number of milliseconds you want the function to be called.